# SQL Server Stored Procedure Output Params in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, php-mssql

I need help running a stored procedure from SQL Server in PHP.  PHP is running on a Unix/Linux server.  We cannot get OUTPUT variables to return in PHP.  The following is the PHP code:

```
$conn = mssql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass');
    mssql_select_db('db', $conn);

    $procedure = mssql_init('usp_StoredProc', $conn);

    $tmpVar1 = 'value';
    $tmpVar2 = 'value2';

    $outVar1 = '';
    $outVar2 = '';

    mssql_bind($procedure, "@var1", $tmpVar1, SQLVARCHAR, false, false);
    mssql_bind($procedure, "@var2", $tmpVar2, SQLVARCHAR, false, false);

    mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar1", $outVar1, SQLVARCHAR, true);
    mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar2", $outVar2, SQLVARCHAR, true);

    mssql_execute($procedure,$conn);

    print($outVar1);
    print($outVar2);
```

The stored procedure looks like so :

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_StoredProc]
(
    @var1 as varchar(36), 
    @var2 as varchar(10), 
    @outVar1 varchar(36) OUTPUT, 
    @outVar2 varchar(36) OUTPUT 
)
as
  select distinct 
    @outVar1 = row1, 
    @outVar2 = row2
  from table1
  where column1 = @var1
    and column2 = @var2
```

Can anyone tell me why $outVar1 and $outVar2 are not being populated?  Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Does mssql_get_last_message() say something useful?

Comment: mssql_get_last_message() returns 'Changed database context to "dbName"'

Comment: Have you tried with a string of 36 spaces?

Comment: Yeah, we've tried specifying the length in the mssql_bind call.  Still no luck.

Comment: No, give it a tailored string: $outVar2 = '   ...36 spaces...   ';

Comment: No luck with the tailored string.

Comment: I know.  This isn't even my project.  I'm trying to help a co-worker out.  But now it's just ticked me off that we haven't figured it out.

Comment: I just ran this script on my windows box via WampServer and guess what. It worked. So apparently Unix/Linux + PHP = Hates MSSQL output params in stored procs.

Comment: As an alternative, you can always SELECT the values you want to get out of the SP and simply grab them from the result set. Granted, this is not as nice as real OUT parameters.

Comment: undefine function mssql_bind Error display

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page on PHP bugs](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21089), you have to (emphasis mine):

> call `mssql_next_result()` for each
>   result set returned by the SP. This
>   way you can handle multiple results.
>
> **When `mssql_next_result()` returns false
>   you will have access to output
>   parameters and return value.**

Comment: You can pass an optional 2nd param to mssql_execute which (if true) gives you immediate access to the results without having to call mssql_next_result...  It still doesn't help here, unfortunately.

Comment: Sounded plausible at first, though. :-\

Comment: This will work if you don't know if there going to be results returned from the stored procedure, i.e. $result = mssql_execute($procedure), works whether there are results returned or not, you can then call mysql_next_result($result) to get at the output params

Answer (score 2):

The second param of execute needs to be true, rather than conn.  This should work:

```
$conn = mssql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass');
mssql_select_db('db', $conn);

$procedure = mssql_init('usp_StoredProc', $conn);

$tmpVar1 = 'value';
$tmpVar2 = 'value2';

$outVar1 = '';
$outVar2 = '';

mssql_bind($procedure, "@var1", $tmpVar1, SQLVARCHAR, false, false);
mssql_bind($procedure, "@var2", $tmpVar2, SQLVARCHAR, false, false);

mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar1", $outVar1, SQLVARCHAR, true);
mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar2", $outVar2, SQLVARCHAR, true);

mssql_execute($procedure,true);

print($outVar1);
print($outVar2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the specific lengths of the output fields

```
mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar1", &$outVar1, SQLVARCHAR, true, false, 36);
mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar2", &$outVar2, SQLVARCHAR, true, false, 36);
```

And see if that makes a difference.

Also note the explicit & to pass the output vars by reference, though I don't know if it's still required or not.

Comment: This would have been my next thought as well, +1. Providing a string of 36 spaces might also serve as a useful test.

Comment: Yeah, we've tried it all with/without lenghths.  With the by-reference params(which throws and error now saying that way is deprecated) and without.

Comment: Regarding the explicit reference passing - don't think this is needed. The documentation states that the function takes references only.

Comment: I have this vague recollection that you used to have to explicitly pass by ref, though I see now that the docs say it's all by ref all the time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is causing your problem, but why are you using `DISTINCT`?

That's just a codesmell - any time you see that, it means that there is a potential for returning duplicates that is being "handled" with DISTINCT, and why duplicates would be returned probably needs to be looked at.

Comment: Distinct could be left out, but we're looking for distinct combinations of row1 and row2.  The stored procedure runs fine if we run it from the SQL Server Management tools.  It's getting the output parameters in php is what we're having trouble with.

Comment: OK.  Keep in mind that on SELECT assignments like this, any time your resultset would contain more than a single row, you will get an error.  Any time the result set is empty, the variables will be unaltered (NULL if they were never assigned).

Comment: Good call, Cade.  But the actual query only returns one row, so that's not it.  This is killing me.  Everything we do with stored procedures works, except retrieving the output params.

Comment: Tomalak is right about having to have consumed all the resultsets before you have access to the OUTPUT parameters. I had trouble with this when I wanted to use the OUTPUT parameters to return count estimates that the client could use prior to consuming the rows - not going to work.

Comment: I've seen this several places, but how would one do this?  You have to execute a stored proc using mssql_execute, which does not return a resource.

Comment: $result = mssql_execute($my_procedure);
while(mssql_next_recordset($result)) {
## do something
}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of PHP you are running, but i think in some of the older ones you needed to pass variables by reference to get the value to come out again:

So you'd need to put the & charcter before the variable when calling the function:

```
mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar1", &$outVar1, SQLVARCHAR, true);
mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar2", &$outVar2, SQLVARCHAR, true);
```

Also according to [this link](http://php.filearena.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php) some versions had a issue with output paramters

Comment: Yeah, we are running php 5.*, forgot the exact version, but those problems shouldn't persist in this version.  The pass-by-reference method throws an error that says 'passing by reference in mssql_bind has been deprecated'

Answer (score 0):

Hm.  A few comments

1) "mssql_execute($procedure,$conn);" is wrong in that the 2nd parameter is not the connection.

2) If you are getting "stored procedure execution failed" then I had to create a DB host in freetds.conf and reference that.

At that point, I don't get errors but I don't get the output params either.  This is PHP 5.1 on RHEL5.

If I enable freeTDS logging, I see the data come back in the return packet.  At this point, I don't know why it isn't working either (other than the SQL server support for PHP is a bit lacking!)

Comment: Thanks, Joe.  We had already removed the $conn param from mssql_query. Yeah, I just ran this script from my Windows box via WampServer and it worked fine.  So, I believe you're right in that SQL Server support is a bit lacking in PHP on Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problems.

Presuming that you are using the FreeTDS driver to communicate with SQL Server there is a known issue with the way the driver works. It's highlighted in the FAQ

**http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#ms.output.parameters**

The API docs for what is suggested in the FAQ is here but I can't find a way to access this with PHP:

http://www.freetds.org/reference/a00276.html

I still can't get this hooked up and I am at the point where I am going to give up on output parameters all together.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this through Adodb Library in very simple manner...

$addProduct = $obj->ExecuteQuery("Begin;DECLARE @ProductCode as varchar (100) ;EXEC CREATEPRODUCT'$pname', '$price', @ProductCode OUTPUT, '$merchantId';select @ProductCode;End;");

$productCode = $addProduct[0][0];

for more explanation you can visit this site..
http://developer99.blogspot.com/2011/07/calling-ms-sql-sp-from-php.html