# Cannot retrieve output parameters from SQL Server stored procedure using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, parameters

I am executing a SQL Server stored procedure that is supposed to return an output parameter (ErrCode), as well as a resultset.

I am calling the procedure from PHP using the following code, but so far have been unable to retrieve the output parameter:

```
$stmt = mssql_init("addFaculty", $this->db);

mssql_bind($stmt, "@FacultyID", $FacultyID, SQLCHAR);
...imagine other parameters here...
mssql_bind($stmt, "@ErrCode", &$ErrCode, SQLINT1, TRUE, FALSE, 1);

$result = mssql_execute($stmt);

echo $ErrCode
```

$ErrCode is always echoed as 0, even when it should return a '1' or '2'. When I execute the procedure within SQL Server Studio, however, the 'Messages' tab will correctly display a '1' or a '2'.

In doing research, I found one suggestion that stated you must use `mssql_next_result()` first to be able to access the output parameters. I tried this, but it simply returned a PHP

> "Warning: mssql_next_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL_result resource"

I also found a reference to a similar issue in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480991/mssql-stored-procecure-output-params-in-php) but did not see a real resolution.

Like the person in that thread, I am using Linux (CentOS) with PHP5 and MS SQL Server 2005.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this? I had an issue like this in a previous project as well, and in the end, simply gave up on using output parameters (and did all my error_checking in the PHP instead) because I couldn't figure it out. It would be nice to find an answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not a PHP guy, but I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626303(SQL.90).aspx) will help.

It says:

> Note that when retrieving an output or
>   input/output parameter, all results
>   returned by the stored procedure must
>   be consumed before the returned
>   parameter value is accessible.

Comment: Hi Kirtan,

Thanks for the link. Unfortunately this did not resolve my issue. It looks like for the link you provided they are using a windows server and using different drivers. Perhaps the fact I am on linux is part of the problem, but I feel like there must be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Have you tried [ADODB](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Check my post on this problem, I used a class extended from Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.  I do not use pure PHP, still using the framework accordingly. Seens to be fine and run ok, I am even getting also the resultset back! Hope it helps:

[Execute MSSQL stored procedure via Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732571/execute-mssql-stored-procedure-via-zend-framework/6663423#6663423)