# Calling Stored Procedure and Display Output in Php MS Sql

Tags: php, sql-server, php-7

i have a problem to display the output of the stored procedure after success run the procedure...i hope everyone can help me....here my stored procedure..

```
$sql = "EXEC [dbo].[sp_mRetailerRegInfo_Add] '$var1','$var2','$var3','$var4','',''";
```

This my sample data in my SP

```
 EXEC sp_mRetailerRegInfo_Add 'asdf','asdf','bacc@abc.com','123', @RetailerId output, @ErrorCode output
```

and this is my sample code ..i can run the procedure but it's not display the output

```
<?php

$serverName = "localhost";

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}



//-----------------------------------------------
// Perform operations with connection.
//-----------------------------------------------
$sql = "EXEC [dbo].[sp_mRetailerRegInfo_Add] '$var1','$var2','$var3','$var4','',''";


$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Your code is fail.';
}
else {
    echo 'Success!';
    echo $result;
}

?>
```

the output will be like this (ID0001) and but i get the output like this

> Connection established.
>
> Success!Resource id #3

Answer (score 1):

With a stored procedure, you would use an `OUTPUT` parameter that you would assign a value to within the procedure. When the procedure finishes, you would access that parameter and use the contents of it however you need.

You can read through [Return Data from a Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx) on the MSDN site to get an idea of how to write a stored procedure.

You will want to take a look at [this already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480991/sql-server-stored-procedure-output-params-in-php) that gives some details on how to access the `OUTPUT` parameter from `PHP`. You would want the second answer there:

> The second param of execute needs to be true, rather than conn. This
>   should work:
>
> ```
> $conn = mssql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass');
> mssql_select_db('db', $conn);
>
> $procedure = mssql_init('usp_StoredProc', $conn);
>
> $tmpVar1 = 'value';
> $tmpVar2 = 'value2';
>
> $outVar1 = '';
> $outVar2 = '';
>
> mssql_bind($procedure, "@var1", $tmpVar1, SQLVARCHAR, false, false);
> mssql_bind($procedure, "@var2", $tmpVar2, SQLVARCHAR, false, false);
>
> mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar1", $outVar1, SQLVARCHAR, true);
> mssql_bind($procedure, "@outVar2", $outVar2, SQLVARCHAR, true);
>
> mssql_execute($procedure,true);
>
> print($outVar1);
> print($outVar2);
> ```

If you could provide the definition for your stored procedure, I could elaborate more specifically on how to set up your `PHP` call.

Comment: Hi @gmiley: i just want to display my output of SP (like example RetailerId) after success insert the data based on my sample code in my question..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible. There's a function called `mssql_bind` for binding the value to a PHP variable

To Call the SP and to store the Output. Try something like this

```
DECLARE @appout int; -- variable to hold the data returned by SP.

EXEC checkFollowing 10,20, @output = @appout OUTPUT; -- This is how i will call a SP.

@appout - will hold the data returned by the procedure.
```

So you can do execute your output parameter as below  :

```
$outVar1 = '';

mssql_bind($procedure, "@appout", $outVar1, SQLVARCHAR, true);

mssql_execute($procedure,true);

print($outVar1);
```